# JQUERY Change TD style ONLY IF IT contains input type = text (and not input type=radio)

Tags: jquery, css, forms, html-table, radio-button

I have applied a style as follows and it works great for me:

```
$("td[id='cellId']").css("text-align", "left");
```

However, I need that style to only be applied to the TD IF it contains textboxes and NOT radio buttons.

I have searched hi and low, but `find()`, `contains()` and the likes, does not seem to be working.

Comment: Do you really mean to use `id=`? IDs should be unique.

Comment: And you should use `#cellId` rather than `[id=cellId]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to filter TD-s which contain textboxes and NOT radio buttons, then you need to use `:has` and `:not` combination:

```
 $("td:not(:has(input[type='radio']))").has("input[type='text']").css("background", "red");
```

Here is a snippet where filtered cells got a red background. You can apply any style to them.

```js
$("td:not(:has(input[type='radio']))").has("input[type='text']").css("background", "red");
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text">cell-1-1</td>
  <td><input type="radio">cell-1-2</td>
  <td><input type="text"><input type="radio">cell-1-3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="radio">cell-2-1</td>
  <td><input type="text">cell-2-2</td>
  <td>cell-2-3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:has()` selector to match elements that contain other elements.

```
$("td#cellId:has(:text)").css("text-align", "left");
```

Answer (score 0):

First note that your `$("td[id='cellId']")` is rather surprising: I may guess that you have some `var cellId` which contains the cell id, so you should use `$('#' + cellId)`.

Now, since you didn't precise about the (eventually) nested elements in the td, we must *ensure* there is no radio button inside it.
Anyway let's suppose we have `var cellElem` that you've populated as needed (may be like showed above).

So you may use something like this:

```
if (!cellElem.find([type=radio]).length) {
    cellElemn.css(textAlign: 'left');
}
```