# Select first div not in class name using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello How do you `find element` not in this class name?

**drop-area__itemPage**

I use this but not working

```js
$("#drop-area").children("div").find(".drop-area__item:not('.drop-area__itemPage:first')")
```

```js
$("#drop-area").children("div").find(".drop-area__item")
    div#page1.drop-area__item.ui-droppable.drop-area__itemPage
    div#page2.drop-area__item.ui-droppable.ui-droppable-active
    div#page3.drop-area__item.ui-droppable.ui-droppable-active
    div#page4.drop-area__item.ui-droppable.ui-droppable-active
    div#page5.drop-area__item.ui-droppable.ui-droppable-active
    div#page6.drop-area__item.ui-droppable.ui-droppable-active
    div#page7.drop-area__item.ui-droppable.ui-droppable-active
    div#page8.drop-area__item.ui-droppable.ui-droppable-active
    div#page9.drop-area__item.ui-droppable.ui-droppable-active
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: unable to understand what you want to do. please specify clearly

Comment: Can you explain more..... your html structure and which div you want to select

Comment: can you share fiddle link?

Comment: `$("#drop-area").find("div .drop-area__item").not('.drop-area__itemPage').first();`?

Comment: yes it's work thank you......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet showing selection of first child which has one class and do not has another one:

```js
$("#drop_area").find("div.class1:not([class~='class3']):first").css("border", "5px blue solid");
```

```css
.class1, .class2, .class3{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
}
.class1 {
    background: teal;
}
.class2 {
    background: tomato;
}
.class3 {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drop_area">
    <div class="class1 class3 class2">class1 class3 class2</div>
    <div class="class2">class2</div>
    <div class="class1 class2">class1 class2</div>
    <div class="class3 class1">class3 class1</div>
    <div class="class1">class1</div>
    <div class="class2">class2</div>
    <div class="class1 class2">class1 class2</div>
    <div class="class3 class1">class3 class1</div>
    <div class="class3">class3</div>
    <div class="class2">class2</div>
    <div class="class3 class2">class3 class2</div>
    <div class="class3 class1">class3 class1</div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

So result jquery statement looks like:

```
$("#drop-area .drop-area__item:not('.drop-area__itemPage'):first")
```

Comment: Here is one more example of selecting element by its content (not class): http://stackoverflow.com/a/41309490/4206079

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a bit of a guess at what you're trying to do, but if you want to find the first child div of `drop-area` that does not have the class `drop-area__itemPage`, you can do this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#drop-area").find(".drop-area__item").not('.drop-area__itemPage').first().css({
    'color': 'red'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drop-area">
  <div id="page1" class=".drop-area__item ui-droppable drop-area__itemPage">1</div>

  <div id="page2" class="drop-area__item ui-droppable ui-droppable-active">2</div>

  <div id="page3" class="drop-area__item ui-droppable ui-droppable-active">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First select all related elements, than exclude with class `.drop-area__itemPage` and than use `.eq(0)` to select first of them:

```
$('#drop-area div .drop-area__item.:not(.drop-area__itemPage)').eq(0);
```